# How do I create adhoc connections on android (WiFi or Bluetooth)

Tags: android, bluetooth, wifi, adhoc

I have done some research and know that android doesn't supply the ability to make adhoc connections (at least over WiFi) in it's default state.  Is there any libraries which allow adhoc connections between android phones with either bluetooth or WiFi?

There should be some way to communicate between devices with bluetooth at the very least, but I haven't found any information on how to do that.

Comment: I found out how to do this with bluetooth.  Pair, Connect, then transfer data.  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html